# UIWebView is not resizing in iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, ios8

I am working on table view based iOS application for iOS 7 and iOS8 using XIB, where I need to display UIWebView as footer view of table view. I have added UIWebView in my XIB, I don't know why I can't able to scroll full UIWebView according to the contents, it seems like locked.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {

    webViewSocial.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    CGFloat height = [[webViewSocial stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
    CGFloat width = [[webViewSocial stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];
    CGRect frame = webViewSocial.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    frame.size.width = width;
    webViewSocial.frame = frame;

    tblAlerts.tableFooterView = webViewSocial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of your webView delegate method is "aWebView" but you're using "webViewSocial" in the method body. If you intend to apply the implementation to whichever webView called it, you'll need to match the local variable to the name of the parameter. That is unless "webViewSocial" is an ivar (in which case I'd use the _ prefix just to avoid confusion. If it's a property of your class I'd use self.webViewSocial.

Comment: Thanks bro for your answer, i have already tried to change UIWebView name "webViewSocial" with "aWebView", still my problem is same.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the delegate method is being called when it's supposed to?

Comment: yes it's calling perfectly, above my code is working fine for iOS 7 but not in iOS8.

Comment: Since the code is fine then I'm guessing it's an auto layout issue. iOS 8 has added a bunch of (annoying) stuff with auto layout and view classes in storyboard. I had to turn auto layout off myself to get some webView stuff working properly a few weeks ago.

Comment: But i have already disabled auto layout of my web view using xib.

Comment: Just to check...open the source code (XML) for your storyboard and see if it says "AutoLayout=YES" toward the top. If it does the only thing you can do is remove this text. It's a wild card, but this is how I was able to get it working myself...

Comment: If your project has a storyboard file, try right clicking on the file and view as source code. See if "AutoLayout=YES" is in there. If so, remove.

Comment: sorry bro, i have deleted storyboard file before due to XIB from my XCODE.

Comment: OK well it was worth a shot. I don't use XIB files - I prefer the advantages that storyboards provide. And I wasn't a developer pre-Xcode 5.0 so I never had to... Good luck!!!! If I think of anything else I'm chime in...

Answer (score 0):

This is Swift 3 version

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        var frame = yourWebView.frame
        frame.size.height = 1
        let fittingSize = yourWebView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
        frame.size = fittingSize
        heightOfyourWebView.constant = fittingSize.height
        tblAlerts.tableFooterView = yourWebView;
     }
```